# Suddenly, the app stopped working（Heroku）

Tags: heroku

Please excuse me for asking a basic question.
I'm using auto translation to ask a question（from Japan）

The app that I had deployed to Heoku suddenly became unusable.

I haven't touched the app at all.

Please refer to the video from the start of the application until the error is displayed, as well as the terminal comments with 'heroku logs --tail' comand.

(the video is edited short. It actually takes about 50 seconds from the start of the application to the display of the error code)

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/WCNUgRssm6o)

Thank you,

Comment: SequelizeConnectionError is thrown which probably means the server cannot connect to the specified database, please check the credentials and verify you can connect to it

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue and solved my problem.

The cause was the end of support for the stack(heroku16) I was deploying the app on.

I will try to update the stack and also re-deploy the app.

Thank you,

Comment: I am happy to hear that :)